# vswprintf_l extended locale version of vswprintf?

Tags: c++, ios, c

Does anyone know when would be the case to use vswprintf_l instead of vswprintf?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `vswprintf_l` takes one extra argument of type `locale_t` at the end. This means you can call `vswprintf_l` using a specified locale rather than the currently set locale. If you pass NULL as the argument for `locale_t` the C locale will be used.